# Is Javascript .contains() available in Babel for Node and React?

Tags: node.js, babeljs, ecmascript-6

Basically looking for an alternative to `"jdklajsdf".indexOf('d') !== -1` that works with the latest Babel. Also for arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. [`String.prototype.includes`](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-String.prototype_methods_String.prototype.includes) With core-js of course (aka [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/)).

Comment: It'd be good to explicitly call out what the function s called, rather than just linking to some docs.

Comment: Well, it’s `String.prototype.contains` as mentioned in the question. I thought it was obvious.

Comment: But it's not, it's `String.prototype.includes`, you linked right to it :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. `.contains` is the nodejs version. You’re right.